# react-hook-forms's onSubmit function not getting triggered in my code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, yup

Why the function onSubmit does not get triggered in my code? (I need to keep it all as it is, or ar least to function in the same manner,  the Input tag I have managed by Controller, needs to show a state "price" all the time, which is changed by two functions (handlePriceInputChange, handleSelectedBox)

```
const schema = yup
  .object({
    voucherPrice: yup.number().positive().required(),
  })
  .required();

function PriceSelection(props) {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("does not work?", data);
  };

  const classes = useStylesPriceSelection();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");

  const handleSelectedBox = (ev) => {
    console.log("", price);
    setSelected(ev.target.getAttribute("data-boxprice"));
    setPrice(parseInt(ev.target.getAttribute("data-price")));
  };

  const handlePriceInputChange = (ev) => {
    console.log("change", price);
    setPrice(parseInt(ev.target.value));
  };

  const priceBox1 = 25;
  const priceBox2 = 50;
  const priceBox3 = 75;
  const priceBox4 = 100;

  return (
    <div>
      <section className={classes.priceBoxWrap}>
        <div
          data-boxprice="1"
          data-price={`${priceBox1}`}
          onClick={(ev) => handleSelectedBox(ev)}
          className={clsx(
            classes.priceBox,
            ((selected === "1" && price === priceBox1) ||
              price === priceBox1) &&
              classes.priceBoxSelected
          )}
        >
          {`${priceBox1}€`}
        </div>

        <div
          data-boxprice="2"
          data-price={`${priceBox2}`}
          onClick={(ev) => handleSelectedBox(ev)}
          className={clsx(
            classes.priceBox,
            ((selected === "2" && price === priceBox2) ||
              price === priceBox2) &&
              classes.priceBoxSelected
          )}
        >
          {`${priceBox2}€`}
        </div>
      </section>

      <section className={classes.priceBoxWrap}>
        <div
          data-boxprice="3"
          data-price={`${priceBox3}`}
          onClick={(ev) => handleSelectedBox(ev)}
          className={clsx(
            classes.priceBox,
            ((selected === "3" && price === priceBox3) ||
              price === priceBox3) &&
              classes.priceBoxSelected
          )}
        >
          {`${priceBox3}€`}
        </div>

        <div
          data-boxprice="4"
          data-price={`${priceBox4}`}
          onClick={(ev) => handleSelectedBox(ev)}
          className={clsx(
            classes.priceBox,
            ((selected === "4" && price === priceBox4) ||
              price === priceBox4) &&
              classes.priceBoxSelected
          )}
        >
          {`${priceBox4}€`}
        </div>
      </section>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Controller
          name="voucherPrice"
          control={control}
          defaultValue={false}
          rules={{ required: true }}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value, ref, ...field } }) => (
            <Input {...field} onChange={(ev) => handlePriceInputChange(ev)} value={price} type="number" innerRef={ref} />
          )}
        />

        <p>{errors.voucherPrice?.message}</p>

        <Button
          variant="contained"
          sx={{ mt: 1, mr: 1 }}
          type="submit"
        >
          {"Continue"}
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PriceSelection;
```

Comment: did your handleSubmit function called e.preventDefault?

Comment: where would it call it from? That is the whole component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `react-hook-form` for this situation and can get rid of the additional local state management via `useState`. I reworked your example and removed the `data` attributes and just passed the price values for each box via the `onClick` callback.

```
const schema = yup
  .object({
    voucherPrice: yup.number().positive().required()
  })
  .required();

const priceBox1 = 25;
const priceBox2 = 50;
const priceBox3 = 75;
const priceBox4 = 100;

const selectedStyles = { outline: "2px solid green" };

function PriceSelection(props) {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors },
    setValue,
    watch
  } = useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(schema) });

  const voucherPrice = watch("voucherPrice");

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  const setVoucherPrice = (price) => () => setValue("voucherPrice", price);

  return (
    <div>
      <section>
        <div
          className="pricebox"
          style={voucherPrice === priceBox1 ? selectedStyles : null}
          onClick={setVoucherPrice(priceBox1)}
        >
          {`${priceBox1}€`}
        </div>

        <div
          className="pricebox"
          style={voucherPrice === priceBox2 ? selectedStyles : null}
          onClick={setVoucherPrice(priceBox2)}
        >
          {`${priceBox2}€`}
        </div>
      </section>

      <section>
        <div
          className="pricebox"
          style={voucherPrice === priceBox3 ? selectedStyles : null}
          onClick={setVoucherPrice(priceBox3)}
        >
          {`${priceBox3}€`}
        </div>

        <div
          className="pricebox"
          style={voucherPrice === priceBox4 ? selectedStyles : null}
          onClick={setVoucherPrice(priceBox4)}
        >
          {`${priceBox4}€`}
        </div>
      </section>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Controller
          name="voucherPrice"
          control={control}
          rules={{ required: true }}
          defaultValue={0}
          render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
            <Input {...field} type="number" innerRef={ref} />
          )}
        />

        <p>{errors.voucherPrice?.message}</p>

        <Button variant="contained" sx={{ mt: 1, mr: 1 }} type="submit">
          {"Continue"}
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Basic (forked)]

Comment: the problem is I need that, if the user types anything on the input, it is evaluated on the classes of the price buttons, so they are marked if the user types in a price equal to one of those buttons

Comment: nothing, I found out `voucherPrice` is being updated as a string, it is all fine now, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If the handleSubmit function does not call e.preventDefault your page will refresh, to fix this you can wrap the handler like this:

```
...
const _handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    handleSubmit(e)
}
...
<form onSubmit={_handleSubmit}>
...
```